# Does my Canon 24-105mm have an issue with IS?

Tags: canon, image-stabilization

I have a Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS USM. After using this lens for a day or so, I have noticed a problem with the image stabilizer.

It works fine with slow shutter speeds at F/4, but causes a lot of image blur at higher F stops. I took the same picture at 1/10sec and F/18 with the IS switched on and then off.

The picture with it switched off was much clearer (yes this was hand held and the subject was static). With IS switched on there is a distinct diagonal movement of the image in the viewfinder just after the picture is taken. At F/4 this problem doesn't exist and I'm beginning to think it is faulty. I have read reports of faulty diaphragms with this lens so maybe when it closes to F/18 it is affecting the IS. Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: I think you'll be able to edit your post and add the images once you reach 10 rep (2 question upvotes or one answer upvote). Maybe there's another question on this site you could provide an insightful answer to?

Comment: Not sure if you were holding it in the way to cause it to give you blurry pictures but you could try it with a tripod to see if gives you the same result. I own a 70-200 f4 with IS and haven't really seen it give that kind of behavior that you describe.

Comment: I normally hold it with one hand on the zoom ring. I have tried it on a tripod and get the same results although I've read the IS should be turned off when using a tripod because of possible feedback! Using mirror lock up improves things but that's not really practical. I'm beginning to think it is faulty because I get the same results when the lens is used on my other camera.

Comment: I bought this lens few days ago and got the exact same problem. I have sent it back and am waiting for the feedback from the supply.
Yao

Comment: My lens has now been to Canon for investigation and repair and they effectively say no fault found. I am still seeing the same problem. If this is the norm for an L series lens then I am very disappointed. I have a Canon EF-S 15-85mm and a Sigma 120-400mm lens and the image quality from them is much better under the same conditions of high F stop and slow shutter with IS on.

Answer (score 4):

I did some testing with my 24-105, and I don't see any of the issues you describe, so I suspect you may have a faulty lens.

Even if you didn't buy it there, I suggest you take it to the local camera shop and talk to them. They'll probably have the same lens to compare it to side by side.

Answer (score 1):

whats the serial number of your lens? i have experienced the same problem on all lenses with serial number 41XXXXX. i have exchanged the unit several times and found out that all of them have the same issue. Finally got a lens with serial number 39XXXXX and the issue was gone. i even wrote to canon europe hoping they can shed a light regarding this, but they are unaware of the issue they just asked me to bring my lens to their service center.

this is the letter that i sent, kindly use the links as they may exactly describe what you are experiencing and if they do, replace your lens because at this moment canon is still clueless about this.

"I recently aquired EF 24-105mm F/4L, with serial number 41XXXXX. everything is excellent with regards to this lens except this particular issue that i found with the lens:

Handheld shooting with IS switched to "ON", i always get a blurry image with a diagonal pattern whenever i step down (f4.5 and onwards) the aperture. At  f4 (wide open) shooting with "IS  ON," image appears to be fine, but when you step down to f4.5 (narrow down) and onwards the blur occurs. Less blurriness appears when "IS" is "OFF", which is very odd for this lens to function like this.

However, if you press shutter button halfway then press DOF preview button simultaneously, and then fully press the shutter (without releasing DOF preview) image blur disappears. I believe that the len is at fault here. lens tested on different body (full frame and crop body) same results. I have exchanged the product from the dealer several times but all units exhibits the same issue.
The dealer is clueless and we're on a dead end here, he also doesn't seem to know what to do.

We tried testing the same lens on tripod with "IS OFF" on a (full and crop sensor body) all images at all stops are fine.

Just to inform you i am not the only one experiencing this issue. kindly refer to this links as they are EXACTLY having the same trouble that i have.

http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/41879017
and
XXhttp://www.flickr.com/groups/canon24-105/discuss/72157631750023066/

For the record it was reported by one user that CANON SERVICE CENTER was able to correct it by changing the FIRMWARE of the LENS. kindly refer to this link.

http://photo.net/canon-eos-digital-camera-forum/00av8d?start=20

i hope this issue will soon be addressed. hoping to hear good news from your end. thank you very much."